# How to check if a variable is scalar in julia

Tags: julia

I would like to check if a variable is scalar in julia, such as Integer, String, Number, but not AstractArray, Tuple, type, struct, etc. Is there a simple method to do this (i.e. `isscalar(x)`)

Comment: How about `isa(x, Number) || isa(x, String)`

Comment: (Presumably you could also add `Char` to that list)

Comment: Thanks, so probably listing all scalar types is the simplest solution. I'll go through the julia type page.

Comment: I'm not sure if I miss any scalar but here it goes: `isscalar(x) = isa(x, Union{Number,AbstractString,Char,Bool})`. This misses out the Nullable however!

Comment: I suppose whether you want to consider `null` a scalar or not is up for debate (e.g. note that a 'null array' is not the same as an 'array of nulls') ... but if you _did_ want to consider it, I suppose adding a `|| isnull(x)` to your definition is possible. The choice of union is interesting; I have no idea if this is more efficient (I would assume that it is not, but I may be wrong).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The notion of what is, or is not a scalar is under-defined without more context.
Mathematically, a scalar is defined; ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(mathematics)))

> A scalar is an element of a **field** which is used to define a **vector space**.

That is to say, you need to define a vector space, based on a field, before you can determine if something is, or is not a scalar (relative to that vector space.).
For the right vector space, tuples could be a scalar.

Of-course we are not looking for a mathematically rigorous definition.
Just a pragmatic one.

#### Base it off what Broadcasting considers to be scalar

I suggest that the only meaningful way in which a scalar can be defined in julia, is of the behavior of broadcast.
As of Julia 1:

```
using Base.Broadcast

isscalar(x::T) where T = isscalar(T)
isscalar(::Type{T}) where T = BroadcastStyle(T) isa Broadcast.DefaultArrayStyle{0}
```

See the docs for [Broadcast](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/interfaces/#man-interfaces-broadcasting-1).

In julia 0.7, `Scalar` is the default. So it is basically anything that doesn't have specific broadcasting behavior, i.e. it knocks out things like array and tuples etc.:
    using Base.Broadcast

```
isscalar(x::T) where T = isscalar(T)
isscalar(::Type{T}) where T = BroadcastStyle(T) isa Broadcast.Scalar
```

In julia 0.6 this is a bit more messy, but similar:

```
isscalar(x::T) where T = isscalar(T)
isscalar(::Type{T}) where T = Base.Broadcast._containertype(T)===Any
```

The advantage of using the methods for `Broadcast` to determine if something is scalar, over using your own methods, is that anyone making a new type that is going to act in a scalar way must make sure it works with those methods correctly
(or actually nonscalar since scalar is the default.)

---

#### Structs are not not scalar

That is to say: sometimes structs are scalar and sometimes they are not and it depends on the struct.

Note however that these methods do *not* consider `struct` to be non-scalar.
I think you are mistaken in your desire to.

Julia structs are not (necessarily or usually) a collection type.
Consider that: `BigInteger`, `BigFloat`, `Complex128` etc etc
are all defined using structs

I was tempted to say that having a `start` method makes a type nonscalar, but that would be incorrect as `start(::Number)` is defined.
(This has been [debated a few times](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/7903))

Comment: You are correct, structs or composite objects should be scalars to be consistent with existing "struct" numbers. Thanks a lot for your definition of scalar using Broadcast.Scalar. I wish broadcast can be applied to subarray (i.e. broadcast to slices of array). But it seems break the concept of broadcast.

Comment: @Phuoc ask that as a seperate question. I'ld be interested to see the answers.

Comment: The link to Broadcast.Scalar doesn't show any definition for Scalar.

Comment: That is a link to `Broadcast`. The next sentence is starts with the word _Scalar_

Comment: Also I think it may have changed Abit since Julia 0.7-prerelease. so the terms might be different. I will look into and update the answer.

Comment: In Julia 0.7, it says :
`WARNING: Broadcast.Scalar is deprecated, use DefaultArrayStyle{0} instead.
 in module Broadcast
Base.Broadcast.DefaultArrayStyle{0}`

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, I am copying Tasos Papastylianou's answer from the comments to here. If all you want to do is distinguish scalars from arrays you can use:

`isa(x, Number)`

This will output true if x is a [Number](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/numbers/) (like a float or an int), and output false if x is an [Array](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/) (vector, matrix, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I found myself needing to capture the notion of if something was scalar or not recently in [MultiResolutionIterators.jl](https://github.com/oxinabox/MultiResolutionIterators.jl/blob/master/src/core.jl).

I found the boardcasting based rules from the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47764659/179081),
did not meet my needs.

In particular I wanted to consider strings as nonscalar.

I defined a trait,
bases on `method_exists(start, (T,))`,
with some exceptions as mentioned e.g. for `Number`.

```
abstract type Scalarness end
struct Scalar <: Scalarness end
struct NotScalar <: Scalarness end

isscalar(::Type{Any}) = NotScalar() # if we don't know the type we can't really know if scalar or not
isscalar(::Type{<:AbstractString}) = NotScalar() # We consider strings to be nonscalar
isscalar(::Type{<:Number}) = Scalar() # We consider Numbers to be scalar
isscalar(::Type{Char}) = Scalar() # We consider Sharacter to be scalar
isscalar(::Type{T}) where T = method_exists(start, (T,)) ? NotScalar() : Scalar()
```

Something similar is also done by [AbstractTrees.jl](https://github.com/Keno/AbstractTrees.jl/blob/d2096ba3a3b23fd4f70e619cdf6810708a54e22d/src/AbstractTrees.jl#L26)

```
isscalar(x) == applicable(start, x) && !isa(x, Integer) && !isa(x, Char) && !isa(x, Task)
```